# iOS9 Passbook/Wallet - Suggest on Lock Screen

Tags: ios9, lockscreen, passbook, coupon, wallet

I have just noticed that all passes added to Passbook/Wallet on iOS9 have, by default, the option "Suggest on Lock Screen" disabled, while on iOS8 they were enabled.

And I have noticed that passes added from apps have the option enabled while passes added via QR code does not.

Does anyone know if possible to add any configuration to the pass.json in order to enable the suggest on lock screen for a specific voucher/pass?

I cannot find any information about it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a bug that has been present since beta 2 of iOS 9.  Worse than disabling updates, the Wallet app calls the unregister endpoint of the web service which causes developers problems because the service is requesting unregistration of a pass that has never been registered.

Comment: Thank you @PassKit, really interesting. I was not aware of this bug. If you have any news I would appreciate if you would update this thread in the future.

Comment: @MaRco85 It has been fixed in iOS 9.2 beta 1

Comment: Thanks @LorisGuignard. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my knowledge, this is not for the developer to change, however the user has to enable that himself/herself. Therefore to answer your question, no it is unfortunately not possible to change anything in the pass.json to automatically enable or disable the show on lock screen.

If you want to find out more about Apple's Wallet, you can check it out [here](https://developer.apple.com/wallet/) or watch the video from the WWDC 2015 [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-701/).

I found a few more links for you that may help regarding Passkit and passes.

- [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1) you can find a great tutorial on creating passes.
- [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html) you can find the Web Service (server) reference provided by
  apple.
- [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195) you can find the complete guide from Apple and last but not
  least, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012158) you can see the PassKit framework reference.

Hope that helps better now,
Julian

Comment: Hi Julian, I am looking to find some more details and the video does not seems to give any useful information about this. But thanks Anyway.

Comment: added some more links for you @MaRoc85

Comment: No problem. If I find anything else I'll update the list :-)